# php preg_replace € sign with "euro"

Tags: php, preg-replace, simplexml, special-characters, str-replace

I would like to replace the € sign in $XML_COMMENT with "euros" before adding to a xml file.

The € sign not being a utf-8 character I get and error message from simplexml

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addAttribute(): string is not in UTF-8 in ...
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(): output conversion failed due to conv error, bytes 0x82 0x26 0x61 0x6D in ....
```

The euro sign appears in the MySQL (utf-8) database as 'â‚¬'

But appears correctly in the textarea on the webpage.

I tried to use these different str_replace

```
$XML_COMMENT=str_replace('€','euros',$XML_COMMENT)
$XML_COMMENT=str_replace('â‚¬','euros',$XML_COMMENT)
$XML_COMMENT=str_replace(chr(128),'euros',$XML_COMMENT)
$XML_COMMENT=str_replace(chr(0xE2).chr(0×82).chr(0xAC),'euros',$XML_COMMENT)
$XML_COMMENT=str_replace(chr(0x82).chr(0x26).chr(0x61).chr(0x6D),'euros',$XML_COMMENT)
```

without success

FYI: I'm using utf-8 everywhere (MySQL, Web Page and XML)

Here's my code

```
// ? : $XML_COMMENT= "bla bla bla â‚¬ bla bla bla";
// ? : $XML_COMMENT= "bla bla bla € bla bla bla";
// expected : $XML_COMMENT= "bla bla bla euros bla bla bla";

$ProductLog_XML = simplexml_load_file($file);
$ProductUpdate = $ProductLog_XML->order->product->addChild('update');
$ProductUpdate->addAttribute('comment',$XML_COMMENT);
$fp=fopen(file, "w");
fwrite($fp, $ProductLog_XML->asXML());
fclose($fp);
```

Is there any alternative using regex / preg_replace ?

Comment: `I'm using utf-8 everywhere.` No you're not. Most likely your editor is misconfigured and uses another encoding.

Comment: i checked it with utf-8 yes it dosent work with utf-8 encoding where as when i removed the meta tag which specified my charset it worked properly!!!!!  ----  Unable to understand :( whats going which type of character is it?

Comment: @phihag what makes you say that? I don't think the editor has anything to do with my problem since $XML_COMMENT comes from a utf-8 MySQL table fed by a utf-8 webpage.

Comment: @baptme The error message is `string is not in UTF-8`. Therefore, I think it's a safe assumption that a string is not in UTF-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `htmlentities()` to convert all entities including the euro sign, so they appear like `&euro;`.

I would use it in the following manner: `htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES|"ENT_HTML401", "UTF-8", true)`

You may choose to use: `htmlentities($XML_COMMENT, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8", true)`. For a full explanation of what the flags change, visit the link below.
As requested by OP @baptme (see comments).

Source: [php.net reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: can you update your answer with htmlentities($XML_COMMENT, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_IGNORE, "UTF-8", true)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and the following works for me where the original HTML page is in UTF-8 and using &euro which after cURL-ing with PHP spits out as "â‚¬"

```
$nodeValue = str_replace(chr(0xE2).chr(0x82).chr(0xAC), "", $nodeValue)
```